# Send-MailMessage CC and BCC Issues

Tags: powershell

I took an older script for sending emails and was trying to make it so we can cc and send attachments and place it in a function so we can repeatedly use it in our environment.

I am having issues with sending an email with `Send-MailMessage` when there are multiple people I need to CC. I have set some parameters on a function that allow someone to enter a CC or BCC but also some switches that when added to the function will automatically send to certain addresses.

$cc_people returns an error when trying to use as cc.
 "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'cc'. The argument null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain  any null values and then they command again.

```
function Send-IntEmail() {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [alias("Subject")]
        $EnterSubject,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$True)]
        [alias("Body")]
        $EnterBody,

        [alias("cc")]
        $whatcc,
        [alias("bcc")]
        $whatbcc,

        [switch]$AddOnePerson,
        [switch]$AddSecondPerson,

        #[Parameter(Mandatory=$False)]
        [alias("Attach")]
        $attachments
    )

    #These never change
    $CLRRecipient = "EmailEntered@here.com"
    $msg = New-Object Net.Mail.MailMessage
    $smtpServer = "smtp"
    $smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

    $from = "no-reply@here.com"
    $msg.ReplyTo = $from
    $msg.From = $from

    #User defines these when running function
    $msg.To.Add($CLRRecipient)
    $msg.Subject = "$EnterSubject"
    $msg.Body = "$EnterBody" + "$(Get-TimeStamp)"+"`nEmail sent by $env:USERNAME"

    $cc_people = @()
    $bcc_people = @()

    if ($AddOnePerson) {
        $LK = "Email@Address.com"
        $cc_people += $LK
        #Write-Host "Including 1 as CC"
    }
    if ($AddSecondPerson) {
        $BB = "Email2@Address.com"
        $cc_people += $BB
        #Write-Host "Including 2 as CC"
    }
    if ($null -eq $cc) {
       $cc_people += $whatcc
       #Write-Host "Including $whatcc as CC"
    }
    if ($null -eq $bcc) {
       $bcc_people += $whatbcc
    }


    #Put an attachment on the email
    if ($attachments -ne $null) {
        Write-Host "`nYou are attaching the following to your email $Attachments `n Your email is being sent to $clrrecipient" -ForegroundColor Yellow
        $AttachBody = "$EnterBody" + "$(Get-TimeStamp)"+"`nEmail sent by $env:USERNAME"
        Write-Host "happens for every attachment email"

        #Evaluate if there is any CC or BCC
        if ($cc_people -ne $null) {
            ##Evaluate if there is a BCC and send with BCC and CC
            if ($bcc_people -ne $null) {
                Send-MailMessage -To $CLRRecipient -From $from -Subject $EnterSubject -Body $AttachBody -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $attachments -CC $cc_people -Bcc $bcc_people
                Write-Host "`n If you don't seen any errors the email has been sent to $CLRrecipient `n" -ForegroundColor Magenta
                Write-Host "CC: Included to $cc_people" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor DarkYellow
                Write-Host "BCC: Included to $bcc_people"-ForegroundColor DarkGreen
                Break
            } else {
                Write-Host "This made it through the CC Eval and evaluated there wasn't any BCC"
                Send-MailMessage -To $CLRRecipient -From $from -Subject $EnterSubject -Body $AttachBody -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $attachments -cc $cc_people
                Write-Host "CC: Included to $cc_people" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen -BackgroundColor DarkYellow
                Write-Host "`n If you don't seen any errors the email has been sent to $CLRrecipient `n" -ForegroundColor Red
                Break
            }
        }

        if ($bcc_people -ne $null) {
            Send-MailMessage -To $CLRRecipient -From $from -Subject $EnterSubject -Body $AttachBody -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $attachments -Bcc $bcc_people
            Write-Host "`n If you don't seen any errors the email has been sent to $CLRrecipient `n" -ForegroundColor Magenta
            Write-Host "No One is CC on this email" -ForegroundColor DarkGreen
            Write-Host "BCC: Included to $bcc_people"-ForegroundColor DarkGreen
            Break
        }

        #There are no CC or BB on the email just send to To and attachments

        Send-MailMessage -To $CLRRecipient -From $from -Subject $EnterSubject -Body $AttachBody -SmtpServer $smtpServer -Attachments $attachments
        Write-Host "No CC or BCC Included"
        Write-Host "`n If you don't seen any errors the email has been sent to $CLRrecipient `n" -ForegroundColor Gray
        # End Attachments
    }

    $smtp.Send($msg)
    $msg.Attachments.Clear()
    $smtp.SendCompleted
    Write-Host "`n If you don't seen any errors the email has been sent to $CLRrecipient" -ForegroundColor Magenta
}
```

Comment: And these "massive problems" manifest themselves ... how exactly?

Comment: what on _earth_ is this `[string[]]$ccstuff = $cc_people` supposed to do? [*grin*] that is already an array set at `$cc_people = @()` ...

Comment: Besides, why are you mixing `Net.Mail.SmtpClient` and `Send-MailMessage`?

Comment: $cc_people does not work to add the people in -cc within Send-MailMessage it throws an error. I was adapting an old Net.Mail script I will most likely edit that if I can get the cc portion to work

Comment: Well, inspect the variable (`$cc_people | % {"-$_-"}`). Is it empty (no output)? Does it contain an empty value (output `--`)?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have never worked with an array before but when I looked at $cc_people before it goes through the attachment portion it did list the email addresses I had selected

Comment: This is going nowhere. Please reduce the code you posted to an [mcve], run it, then update your question with *that* code and the complete, unaltered error message produced by *that* code. Do not paraphrase. Do not type from memory.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers that is the exact code without our email addresses listed and the error message I listed was word for word what happened. I will look elsewhere for assistance.

Comment: It may be the exact code, but that code is neither minimal (with all the `Write-Host` and `Net.Mail.SmtpClient`), nor is it complete (you don't show how and with what (sample) arguments the function is invoked). Also, PowerShell error messages consist of a lot more than just the plain error message text.